# Integral inequality involving the convex envelope

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Given a function $f\in C([a,b])$, let $F(x) := \int_a^x f(y)\, dy$, $x\in [a,b]$, let $F^{**}$ be the convex envelope of $F$, and define $Tf := (F^{**})'$.

I would like to prove (or disprove) that
$$
(I) \quad \int_a^b |Tf (y) - Tg(y)|\, dy \leq \int_a^b |f(y) - g(y)|\, dy,
\qquad
\forall f,g\in C([a,b]).
$$
My tentative approach is based in trying to prove the following properties for the operator $T$:

(1) $\int_a^b Tf = \int_a^b f$ for every $f\in C([a,b])$;

(2) If $f\leq g$, then $Tf \leq Tg$.

Indeed, if (1) and (2) are true, then (I) will follow from a result by Crandall and Tartar.

Property (1) seems easy. I have problems in proving property (2), that seems correct on the base of some geometrical consideration.

Any advice (for proving (2) or for another approach towards (I)) will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: I have found a proof for (2), but it is long and tricky. I will write it only if there is someone interested.

Comment: What is the convex envelope? The largest convex function majorised by $F$?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that.

Comment: Is the convex envelope of a differentiable function always differentiable?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you have a (maximal) segment in the graph of the envelope, this segment is tangent to the graph of the function at the two extremes.

Comment: As an aside, I think Rockafellar uses $\operatorname{co} F$ for the convex envelope of $F$.